# distance from a point to the nearest edge of a polygon

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, shapely

in the below code i want to calculate the distance from a point to the nearest edge of a polygon.as shown in the results section below, the coordinates are provided.the code posted below shows how i find the distance from a point to the neatrest edge of a polygon.
at run time, and as shown below in restults section, for the give point and geometry, the distance from postgis is equal to 4.32797817574802 while the one calculated from geopandas gives 3.8954865274727614e-05

please let me know how to find the distance from a point to nearest edge of a polygon.

**code**

```
poly = wkt.loads(fieldCoordinatesAsTextInWKTInEPSG25832)
pt = wkt.loads(centerPointointAsTextInWKTInEPSG25832)
print(poly.distance(pt)))
```

**results**:

```
queryPostgreSQLForDistancesFromPointsToPolygon:4.32797817574802#result from postgis using st_distance operator
centerPointointAsTextInWKTInEPSG4326:POINT(6.7419520458647835 51.08427961641239)
centerPointointAsTextInWKTInEPSG25832:POINT(341849.5 5661622.5)
centerPointointAsTextInWKTInEPSG4326:POINT(6.7419520458647835 51.08427961641239)
fieldCoordinatesAsTextInWKTInEPSG25832:POLYGON ((5622486.93624152 1003060.89945681,5622079.52632924 1003170.95198635,5622126.00418918 1003781.73122161,5622444.73987453 1003694.55868486,5622486.93624152 1003060.89945681))
fieldCoordinatesAsTextInWKTInEPSG4326:POLYGON((6.741879696309871 51.08423775429969,6.742907378503366 51.08158745820981,6.746964018740842 51.08233499299334,6.746152690693346 51.08440763989611,6.741879696309871 51.08423775429969))
poly.distance(pt):3.8954865274727614e-05#result from geopandas
```

Comment: Please edit the code in your question, simplified so it is a [mre] - anyone should be able to copy/paste into a file and _without adding anything_ run it to see the same problem as you, so make sure the code includes all needed imports and some data initialization for a simple polygon and the point coordinates that shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- your code works.  It's approx 7000km from Belgium to Ethiopia
- are you sure your data is correct?  Have built a **plotly** graph to show where buffered polygon, polygon centroid and point are located in EPSG:4326 CRS

```
from shapely import wkt
import geopandas as gpd
import plotly.express as px
import json

# queryPostgreSQLForDistancesFromPointsToPolygon:4.32797817574802#result from postgis using st_distance operator
centerPointointAsTextInWKTInEPSG4326 = "POINT(6.7419520458647835 51.08427961641239)"
centerPointointAsTextInWKTInEPSG25832 = "POINT(341849.5 5661622.5)"
centerPointointAsTextInWKTInEPSG4326 = "POINT(6.7419520458647835 51.08427961641239)"
fieldCoordinatesAsTextInWKTInEPSG25832 = "POLYGON ((5622486.93624152 1003060.89945681,5622079.52632924 1003170.95198635,5622126.00418918 1003781.73122161,5622444.73987453 1003694.55868486,5622486.93624152 1003060.89945681))"
fieldCoordinatesAsTextInWKTInEPSG4326 = "POLYGON((6.741879696309871 51.08423775429969,6.742907378503366 51.08158745820981,6.746964018740842 51.08233499299334,6.746152690693346 51.08440763989611,6.741879696309871 51.08423775429969))"
# poly.distance(pt):3.8954865274727614e-05#result from geopandas

poly = wkt.loads(fieldCoordinatesAsTextInWKTInEPSG25832)
pt = wkt.loads(centerPointointAsTextInWKTInEPSG25832)

print(poly.distance(pt)/10**3)

# let's visualize it....
gpoly = (
    gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[poly], crs="EPSG:25832")
    .buffer(10 ** 6)
    .to_crs("EPSG:4326")
)
gpoly.plot()
gpt = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[pt, poly.centroid], crs="EPSG:25832").to_crs(
    "EPSG:4326"
)
px.scatter_mapbox(
    gpt.assign(dist=poly.distance(pt)/10**3),
    lat=gpt.geometry.y,
    lon=gpt.geometry.x,
    hover_data={"dist":":.0f"},
).update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "style": "carto-positron",
        "zoom": 4,
        "layers": [
            {
                "source": json.loads(gpoly.to_json()),
                "below": "traces",
                "type": "fill",
                "color": "red",
            }
        ],
    }
)
```

[image]